# are there standard battery level messages in ROS

Tags: ros, messages

[image: Rosanswers logo]

for developping low level interfaces for a new robot, are there existing standard messages for battery level (in %) or voltage, or thresholds (low) / flags (charging / dis-charging) ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/192938/are-there-standard-battery-level-messages-in-ros/) by [mherrb](https://answers.ros.org/users/80/mherrb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 148 on 2014-09-18

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We [added](https://github.com/ros/common_msgs/pull/74) a [BatteryState](http://docs.ros.org/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/BatteryState.html) message in [sensor_msgs](http://wiki.ros.org/sensor_mgs)

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2017-06-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [shahbaz.ele](https://answers.ros.org/users/72737/shahbaz.ele/) on 2021-03-31**:
Dear can you give some hardware connection example to read battery status from Arduino.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2021-03-31**:
This is very different than the topic of this question. Please don't ask questions in the comments on this site. If you have a question please ask it as a full question.

Related, this looks like a good question for an Arduino forum and not a ROS forum as your question doesn't appear to be ROS related, it would likely be closed as off topic.